# Understanding overriding in in-order tree traversal

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree

I am looking to return the k-th element of a binary tree and came up with this solution:

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left 
#         self.right = right


class Solution:
    def kthSmallest(self, root: Optional[TreeNode], k: int) -> int:
        if not root:
            return None
        out = []
        return self.Search(root,k,out)[k-1]
    def Search(self,root,k,out):
        if root:
        
            # iterate over the tree using DFS, and after the last iteration return the sorted list "out"
            self.Search(root.left,k,out)
            
            self.Search(root.right,k,out)
            out.append(root.val)
        return sorted(out)
```

My question is: Why can't I return sorted(out)[k-1] in the Search method? I have to return the sorted list to the kthSmallest method and then search for the k-th entry and I don't understand why.

Comment: What makes you think you can't? Note, though, that DFS does a *post*-order traversal, not an in-order traversal, because you append all the descendants of a node to `out` before the node itself. (Not that it matters, because you sort the entire  list immediately anyway.)

Comment: However, you are sorting far more than necessary. You could let `kthSmallest` sort the entire list *once*, rather than constantly sorting each sublist before returning it.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the purpose of this code challenge. Can you point to where you got it from, so we can check?